# Remove 'Driving mode' from status bar dropdown?

Tags: notification-bar, driving-mode

I have a Samsung phone with android 4.1.2.

When I slide down the notification bar there are multipls items. One of those are driving mode. I don't drive anywhere (I can't afford a car, gas, insurance, tickets, etc,  and so I use public transportation) so I want to remove the button. This is what I'm talking about:

[image: Notification Bar screenshot (click for larger variant)]
<sup>Notification Bar screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Second over from the right.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the phone **Settings**. Click **Display** from the **Device** group, then on the next screen click **Notification panel**. You can add and remove notification bar items from there.

Not all Samsung ROMs have this option: in particular, I don't think the Galaxy S III had it until 4.1.2.