# How to remove any icons from notification bar?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I want to disable a few buttons like "Driving mode" from the notification bar on my S4.

Yes, I have read [exactly this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/44622/37541) question and I know the general idea. (I have seen it on 4.1).

But on my device with 4.2.2 the problem is: All buttons are enabled and there is no area for disabled buttons to move buttons to.

Is there any secret trick I have missed?

**EDIT**: There are some good screenshots about the situation [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/49364/37541).
And I would be curious, if this is specific to the S4 or specific to 4.2.2?

Comment: +1 I was going to ask the same thing tonight. Also, I would like to know how to add items (wifi) to the menu, but I think I will be able to figure that out once there is an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the [Note 2](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57582691-285/how-to-customize-the-galaxy-note-2-notification-panel), the S4 doesn't have the "Available Buttons" section in the notification panel. So, you cannot remove the items.

Comment: But I have seen pictures of the S4 with a WiFi toggle in the notification panel yet I do not have that toggle. How is that possible?

Comment: @TronicZomB Yes, the S4 has a Wi-Fi toggle. I also have an S4. Is your device an S4?

Comment: @geffchang: So to get this straight: This feature exists on the Note, Note 2 (and possibly others) but was dropped from the S4? Do you happen to know, what factors decide on the existance of this feature?

Comment: @TronicZomB: Yes, my S4 has a wifi button. You might scroll to the left or right. Or use the grid button at the top right to display all buttons in a big grid (totally crowded).

Comment: @Elrond yes I have and tried to customize the notifications area and it's not there.

Comment: @geffchang Okay, this is not the response I had hoped for, but this seems to be the answer. So until there is some better one, I'll accept it.