# Searching for WiFi toggle

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-4, verizon

How do I get the WiFi toggle to show up in the notifications area on the Samsung Galaxy S4 - Verizon - 4.2.2 - Build VRUAME7?

[image: Screenshot]

When I click on the pencil icon to edit it takes me here which doesn't scroll or allow me to edit the notifications except move the order around:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise the toggles by clicking the pencil icon in the top right. You should then be able to add a wifi toggle icon.

Edit: Ok. It seems like Verizon have removed that toggle. If you're rooted you can add it back though. See link [here](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-news/245663-sgs4-hack-add-wifi-toggle-your-samsung-galaxy-s4.html) (contains screenshots).

> You need to download and install SQLite Editor - you need to download and install [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/d...qleditor&hl=en)
>
> 1. Open up SQLite Editor - Select the Apps tab on top and scroll down until you see Settings Storage and click it.
> 2. Click on Settings.db
> 3. Click on system
> 4. Click on the search icon on top right
> 5. Type in the word notification in the Filter Value field and click ok
> 6. Once the results load up, tap on notification_panel_active_app_list (should be the bottom result) and click on the pencil icon on top to
>    edit
> 7. In the Value field, you'll see all your toggles listed. All you have to do is add the word Wifi <-- just like that with a semi colon
>    right after. Make sure there's no space after the semi colon like in
>    the screenshot below. Once you add Wifi, click the save button.
> 8. Close SQLite editor and reboot your phone. Once your phone boots back up, you should now have the Wifi toggle in quick settings!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Already tried it, sorry I should have put that.

Comment: Ok. It seems like Verizon have removed that toggle. If you're rooted you can add it back though. See [link](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-news/245663-sgs4-hack-add-wifi-toggle-your-samsung-galaxy-s4.html)

Comment: Ohh, that's unfortunate. And I can't root yet, I have the new Build version that doesn't have root available yet. I will keep this in mind though. Thanks!

Comment: Would you mind to include an excerpt from what's to be found behind the link? If the link dies, the URL does not help :)